# Postgres restore missing privileges

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am running through some very basic tests to confirm a backup/restore process is working on a local environment.

the issue I am running into is that it doesn't look as though pg_dump/pg_restore/psql is restoring a database to the same state.

A sample of what I am doing below from start to finish.

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb WITH ENCODING='UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    a INT
);

INSERT INTO a(a)
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2;

SELECT * FROM a;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO testuser;
```

Then running the pg_dump

```
pg_dump -Fc -v --host=localhost --username=postgres --dbname=testdb -f C:\test\testdb.dump
```

creating a side by side restore for this example

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb_restore WITH ENCODING='UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

```
pg_restore -v --host=localhost --username=postgres --dbname=testdb_restore C:\test\testdb.dump
```

Now when I right click on testdb in pgadmin and click "Create Script" I get the following

```
-- Database: testdb

-- DROP DATABASE testdb;

CREATE DATABASE testdb
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_Australia.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_Australia.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO postgres;

GRANT TEMPORARY, CONNECT ON DATABASE testdb TO PUBLIC;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;
```

When I click on the perform the same on testdb_restore, I get the following

```
-- Database: testdb_restore

-- DROP DATABASE testdb_restore;

CREATE DATABASE testdb_restore
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_Australia.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_Australia.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

As you can see I am missing the extra privileges from the original database.

I'm sure this is a very simple thing but I am currently lost on this one. I have also tried using methods and also `pg_dump` create database option added in and no difference.

Please note: I am extremely new to postgres and coming from a SQL Server background.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but `INSERT INTO a(a)
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2;` can be simplified to `INSERT INTO a(a) values (1),(2);`

Answer (score 4):

Roles and permissions are stored and managed per cluster, not per database, which is why pg_dump is not dumping them. You should use `pg_dumpall` if you are happy to have a dump of the whole cluster.

Alternatively, you can use `pg_dumpall -r` to dump roles only, and then `pg_dump` your database, and apply both scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the privileges for a database are *not* included in a `pg_dump`. You'd have to use `pg_dumpall` for that, but that dumps *all* databases.

I know this is annoying. It is a bug of long standing that nobody has fixed yet.

Comment: Not even with `pg_restore --create ...`?

Comment: I have not tested it recently, but I think not even with `-C`.